# Can I use the Sandbox and Add to Cart buttons for testing?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Basically, what I want know is whether or not one can test Add to Cart buttons via the sandbox.

I have an Add to Cart button.  I click on on it.  I am directed to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr and asked to click on a link to log me into Paypal.  I do that and then I am directed to developer.paypal.com where I click on "See our New Sandbox."  I then am told to log in again, which I do.  the page refreshes and I am logged in.  I click on the See Our New Sandbox link again and I see two sandbox accounts, a Business and a Personal.  I expand the personal and click on the sandbox link and I am directed to sadbox.paypal.com, where I am asked to log in.  I log in ( with my Paypal account ) and then I am asked to click a link to log in to the sandbox, which I do, and once more I am at developer.sandbox.com, with a "See our New Sandbox" link.  Click on that link and the circular logging in starts again.

I've tried this on IE, Firefox, Chrome, a separate computer, clearing cache and cookies, and even using an Incognito window, but still the same loop.

1. Click Add to Cart
2. Go to Sandbox
3. Click link to log me in to PayPal
4. Click on See Our New Sandbox
5. Login again.
6. Click on See Our New Sandbox.
7. Go to one of my sandbox accounts and click on sandbox site link.
8. Directed to sandbox.paypal.com, log in.
9. Asked to click link to login.
10. Directed to developer.sandbox.com, click on See Our New Sandbox.
11. Go to 6

Months ago, the Sandbox worked great, but now?  Loop after loop.  Is this being addressed?  Can one actually use the Sandbox for Add to Cart buttons?  T

Comment: Could you post what you've tried?

Comment: What I tried is in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i'm aware, the answer to your question is yes. Regarding your problem, I recommend you to open the "Log in into the sandbox" link in a new tab/window, then once you log in, refresh the page that gave you the link, it should work as expected. Another way will be to log in and then go back to your page and click in your Add to Cart button again.

Comment: I deleted all cookies that had anything related to paypal ( had done this before ), cleared my cache, and then restarted the browser, checked for cookies again, there were a few not deleted, so I removed those, cleared the cache again, and was able to get logged in without the circular 'please log in'.

Comment: At this point I was able to click on Merchant services in the Sandbox and went to My Saved buttons. There were none. Then it hit me. You have to create saved buttons on the site you wish to use. I did that, and was asked to login with one of my sandbox accounts, did that, and the test transaction went through.

If anyone from Paypal is following, a bit of documentation that is up to date with the new sandbox would not hurt. or at least remove the out dated old documentation from x.com.